# best approach to connect my custom database to multiple BI tools?

Tags: database, architecture, business-intelligence, connector

I'm developing a read-only SQL engine, with an API that can execute `SELECT` queries (but no other SQL queries).

My question is how to make it available to as many Business Intelligence/Dashboard tools as possible.

I see 2 possible approaches (maybe I missed others):

1. develop a JDBC driver, and ship it to my user, so that they can install it and connect to my service. This is rather straight-forward, but would only work for BI tools that accept installing JDBC drivers
2. try to implement a well known SQL protocol, such as postgresql protocol, so that user can use their regular psql connector in their BI tool. I'm tempted to try this, but I haven't seen it in other product and looks a bit hacky.

What do you think? Option 2 looks the most generic to me, but risky. Is it a sensible approach?

Could I do something else? Or implement, server-side, another generally-accepted protocol?

thx

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly. Why do have a requirement on developing your own SQL engine with support for SELECT only. How would you get your data in your datastore in the first place if there is no support for INSERT? 
Since you mention an API will be created anyway. Why don't you use an existing SQL engine and only define an API endpoint that lets you retrieve data without anything else. Combined with an user account to access the database that only allows select statements to be executed should do the trick if I understand your question correctly.

Comment: @KDW yes I should clarify that. The team I work with is developing an SQL engine with differential privacy (basically adding some noise to the results to protect privacy). So it support SQL SELECT (INSERT is done via a separate process, not in SQL), but the backend is really custom.

Comment: Just a wild thought. Could a different approach be the use of a supported (from BI point of view) database containing replicated data from the "privacy safe" database? Each command towards the safe database is replicated to the shadow database used for BI which can only be SELECTed from...
Your approach will work as well but seems rather difficult to me and potentially prone to errors. Then there is the question: is everybody willing to install an unknown/custom JDBC driver not originating from a DB development organisation (no offence towards you and your organisation of course)?

Answer (score 0):

Variant 2 seems to be more promising in the long term. It is almost unreal that BI tools will add a connector for your proprietary API/protocol as most likely your product is a niche solution.

For example, QuestDB finally adds Postgre-compatible endpoint, SingleStore is accessed with MySql drivers, ClickHouse has plans to add Postgre-endpoint in addition to existing own HTTP/binary protocols.

You mentioned JDBC, so maybe it would be easier to have an endpoint compatible with Presto/Trino REST API (many BI tools already have drivers for PrestoDB).